# How to group by two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am building a chat website, I have a table that contains the following columns, `from_id`, `to_id`, `messages`.

The `from_id` is the `id` of the user that the chat is from and the `to_id` is the `id` of the user the chat is sent to.

Now I want to get all the chats but I also want to group it in such a way that if the `to_id` is my id, it will group it by `from_id` and if the `from_id` is my user id, then it will group it by `to_id`, I tried this `SELECT * FROM chats WHERE from_id=:me || to_id=:me GROUP BY from_id, to_id` but it only group it when the `from_id` and the `to_id` are the same, how can I also make it go the other way round too

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, what do you want to do with the aggregation?  And how does "aggregation" fit in with "I want to get all the chats"?  Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN from_id = :me THEN to_id ELSE from_id END id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(messages) messages -- I added this as an aggregate function
FROM chats 
WHERE :me IN (from_id, to_id) 
GROUP BY id
```

But if you don't need any aggregation, then you should not use `GROUP BY`, but `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN from_id = :me THEN to_id ELSE from_id END id
FROM chats 
WHERE :me IN (from_id, to_id)
```

Comment: how can i get the id of the table

Comment: @EloikeDavid which id? There is no column id in the table. I use id as the alias of the returned column.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is normally used to take multiple rows and to condense them into a single row.  That does not seem to be your intentionl

It sounds like you have an *ordering* problem, not an *aggregation* problem.  If you want to order the chats by the "other" id, you can use:

```
select c.*
from chats c
where :me in (to_id, from_id)
order by (case when :me = to_id then from_id else to_id end);
```

Comment: I want to `group by` not `order by`